# How to use meta tag in a browser version condition (IE 10 and above)?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, meta-tags, conditional-comments

I'm using IE11. And I have to force the browser to act as IE 10 with a condition if the browser is IE11.
Because of Microsoft removed support for **Conditional Comments**, I'm struggling to figure out a way.
I tried this with JavaScript,

```
<script language="JavaScript">
         function setVersion() {
             if (getInternetExplorerVersion() === 11) {
                 debugger;
                 $('head').append('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />');
             }
         }
         //Method to get the IE version
         function getInternetExplorerVersion() {
             var rv = -1;
             if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
                 var ua = navigator.userAgent;
                 var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
                 if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                     rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
             }
             else if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
                 var ua = navigator.userAgent;
                 var re = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
                 if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                     rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
             }
             return rv;
         }
    </script>
```

Now because of      ***getVersion*** is being called after loading the page, this code isn't making any effect. 
Any other way to do this?

Comment: as you already figured out, javascript is imho too late to change the rendering mode. You may either have to do this serverside (for what i have no solution) or you just deliver the X-UA-Compatible with IE=10 in every case?

Comment: Actually that was what I was doing before. But the a part of different page fails to display the vertical scroll in IE10. That part is too much complicated.
I just posted this part because it wont make any complications

Comment: Although I'm trying to figure out some another way @Allanon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use commented conditional comment like this

```
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

in this way ie10 and above will have the tag, instead ie9 and under will not have it cause the condition is not met.

example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.ie8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.ie8.js" defer></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

will load on ie8 the js without the defer, while in ie9 and above (and all other browser) will load the script with defer ignoring the conditional because they count as commented

There a link to the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Downlevel-revealed_conditional_comment) for an explanation.

Comment: OK. But I'm working on IE 11. which does not support Conditional Comments at all. It ignores it as if it's a comment.
Your answer would work perfectly on browsers below IE10.

Comment: infact it will be loaded in ie10 and ie11 with this method and not in ie9 and earlier version, ie10 will act always as ie10 :)

Comment: But my friend 
`<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />

<!--<![endif]-->`

will act as a comment in IE9+ browsers. Hence your code will not work in IE 10 and 11.
I have no problem at all in IE10 or any lower versions.
If it's IE 11, it MUST BE rendered to IE10 not other.

Comment: test it, it will not be commented :) it will appear in this way `<!-- --> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" /> <!-- <![endif] -->` without the internal tag commented, we are using it in owr website and it works perfect

Comment: OK. Let me try, was going to implement a new method, hope this run.

Comment: I understood your second comment now.
So basically it IE 11 will ignore 
 `<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->`

and it will only execute the **meta** tag.
Thanks a lot. I was gonna rewrite a whole method

Answer (score 0):

> I have to force the browser to act as IE 10 with a condition if the browser is IE11.

Why not to use meta tag (or http-header) without any condituion?
IE9- cant act as IE10 and will ignore this.
IE10 will act as IE10 i. e. itself
IE11 will act as IE10 as you want from it
Not sure about Microsoft Edge
All other browsers will ignore it.

> I'm struggling to figure out a way

The best way to detect the mode is `document.documenMode`, but it would be too late for a meta-tag.